# Como contar a quantidade de registros (rows) numa instrução SQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, query, contador

Estou nessa SQL, recuperando os registros (quantidade de fornecedores por cidade) de uma tabela e gostaria de contar quantos registros tem em cada **cidade**. Quero na frente das cidades, colocar algo como **Cidade Tal (9)**. Vou colocar um print do resultado dessa SQL para ajudar a visualizar melhor a pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function getFornsRegion($code)
{
    $this->db->select("fe.*"); 
    $this->db->from("fornecedores_empresa AS fe"); 
    $this->db->where("fe.regiao", $code);
    $this->db->group_by("fe.cidade");

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Tentou `$this->db->select("count(fe.cidade)"); ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Então, podemos colocar um contador dentro da própria instrução SQL e no `result_array()` recuperar o resultado do aliás **contador** conforme pode ser demonstrado no código que segue abaixo:

```
public function getFornsRegion($code)
{
    $this->db->select("fe.*, count(fe.cidade) AS contador, fo.*, ci.*");
    $this->db->from("fornecedores_empresa AS fe");
    $this->db->join("fornecedores AS fo", "fe.idusuario = fo.id");
    $this->db->join("cidade AS ci", "ci.ct_id = fe.cidade");
    $this->db->where("fe.regiao", $code);
    $this->db->where("fo.nivel", 5);
    $this->db->where("fo.status", 1);
    $this->db->group_by("fe.cidade");
    $this->db->order_by("ci.ct_nome", "asc");

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Você conseguiu fazer funcionar com `fe.*`?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert a instrução está funcionando perfeitamente retornando todos os dados da consultar e o contador de registros agrupados por cidades.